# Побитовая запись в обратном порядке

Tags: c++

Задача: взять из консоли два файла и переписать содержимое одного в другой в побитово обратном порядке.

При этом нужно пользоваться средствами С++. В данном случае вывод в прямом порядке выглядит так:

```
ifstream file2(argv[2], ios::binary);
ofstream file1(argv[1]);
copy(
    istream_iterator<char>(file2 >> noskipws),
    istream_iterator<char>(),
    ostream_iterator<char>(file1)
);
```

Для моей задачи преподаватель посоветовал использовать `reverse_iterator`, но я не представляю, как это использовать для работы с битами.

Comment: А биты обратите вручную. Вфигачьте какой-нибудь transform-итератор посередине.

Comment: Или используйте [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) вместо `copy`, чтобы развернуть биты в байте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто обратные итераторы, как я понимаю, требуют двунаправленности, так что минуя промежуточный контейнер - одним `copy` не обойтись...

Проще всего - как-то так:

```
void reverse(istream& in, ostream& out)
{
    vector<unsigned char> v;
    copy(istream_iterator<unsigned char>(in >> noskipws),
         istream_iterator<unsigned char>(),
         back_inserter(v));
    for(auto& x: v)
    {
        x = (x&0x55) << 1 | (x&0xAA) >> 1;
        x = (x&0x33) << 2 | (x&0xCC) >> 2;
        x = (x&0x0F) << 4 | (x&0xF0) >> 4;
    }
    copy(v.rbegin(),v.rend(),ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(out));
}
```

Можно и (проще? сложнее?) - стать на конец файла и идти к началу, читая побайтно. Можно даже написать свой соответствующий итератор, но имеет ли это смысл, если файл небольшой?